# How to Change a VLAN Assignement for an Interface on a Cisco 3750

Tags: cisco, switch, vlan, interface

I'm having some trouble trying to figure out how to Change a VLAN Assignement for an Interface on a Cisco 3750.

I want to change:

```
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/3
switchport access vlan 2
switchport mode access
spanning-tree portfast
!
```

Into:

```
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/3
 switchport access vlan 3
 switchport mode access
 spanning-tree portfast
!
```

However I haven't been able to do it successfully.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
conf t
int g1/0/3
switchport access vlan 3
do wr mem
```

Comment: If you aren't used to it forgetting what mode you're in is a pretty easy mistake.  Especially if you're trying to do a change during a 3am outage.

Answer (score 2):

What have you tried?  It should go something like this:

```
switch# config t
switch(config)#  int gi1/0/3
switch(config-if)#switchport access vlan 3
```

Then ctrl-z and write mem

Comment: it should be 'swichtport access vlan 3' he wants to change from 2 to 3

Comment: shouldn't there be a space in there as well?  Or am I forgetting IOS quicker than I thought.